# Regular expression matching repetitive strings

Tags: regex

I need to match files like the following

```
session1_******.php
```

Do I do something like this?

```
{session1_}^(.*).php
```

Comment: `Do I do something like this?` You mean you even didn't test it?

Comment: Still learning Regex. Syntax is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct answer

```
^session1_.*\.php$
```

A carat (^) is used to indicate the beginning of a string or to negate a character class (e.g. [^abc] ... meaning not "a", "b", or "c"), it has no meaning in the middle of a regex.

Parenthesis are only needed if you need to capture the result.

A period (.) must be escaped.

Assuming this this is the entire string you are matching, the ^...$ require a full match from beginning to end.  If there could be text before the beginning remove the ^, or there could be text as the end remove the $.

Comment: carats are also used to negate character classes.

Comment: Also, if you need to express repetition of a subpattern, it's necessary to use parentheses, regardless of what capturing you're doing.

Comment: Added edit for char class.  I agree on the parens, but technically you could use (?:) instead, which allows repetition without the capturing.

Comment: Technically, using `(?:)` is still using parentheses :)

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match what you seek:

```
^session1_.*\.php$
```

Note the escaped dot `\.` meaning a *literal* dot (not a regex "any character")